# Parallel execution of async task in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, threadpool

I have an `AsyncTask` called `TestTask`  and I need to run the `AsyncTask` 10 times. I am calling the `AsyncTask` inside a `for` loop ten times. I want all the 10 `AsyncTask` to run parallely. How can I implement this?

Comment: Can you post the code you have for calling it and maybe indicate what it does? There may be a better way

Comment: What makes you think that the set of tasks are not already running in parallel?

Comment: As for the actual topic, it is important to realize that the possibility of AyncTasks executing to some degree in parallel, or not, varies between Android versions.

Answer (score 2):

Thread pool is what you are looking for.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html

Comment: Besides the fact that your link really isn't directly related, what the OP is asking for is probably not a good idea since they would be running the same task multiple times without knowing which one will finish in which order.

Comment: @codeMagic - what is your basis for assuming that it matters which finishes first?

Comment: @ChrisStratton the same task is running so, most likely, it is doing the same work which means changing the same variables, files, etc... That would mean that one may be changed before another needs to. Obviously, it is impossible to say if this is a bad approach or not without knowing more about what the task does or what the OP wants. But just assuming that parallel execution is ok here is dangerous.

Comment: @codeMagic - you don't seem to be paying attention to the fact that parallel execution is the explicit goal stated in the question title.

Comment: Generally we do try to answer the question that was asked, yes.  At the least, we don't attack people who try to answer it.  If you have doubts about the question, perhaps you should post those specific concerns on the question, and not on an answer that they have nothing to do with.

Comment: Suffice to say that your both your false criticism that the link is unrelated, and wild speculation about what the question doesn't say, is rather unfair to Besuglov

Answer (score 0):

there is a detailed explanation for ur problem in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36078608/2249287

on top of this link answer,to make ur problem work the solution is execute ur Asynctask using custom executor as below,

```
int mCorePoolSize = 10; (u can increase this number as well)
    int mMaximumPoolSize = 80;
    int mKeepAliveTime = 10;
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(mMaximumPoolSize);
    Executor mCustomThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(mCorePoolSize, mMaximumPoolSize, mKeepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
    YourAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(mCustomThreadPoolExecutor);
```

and u can also verify whetehr all the 10 AsyncTask to running parallely in studio as shown in that link...

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int x=0;x<=10;x++)
{
     new TestTask().execute(args...)
}
```

Comment: wrong answer it will still be executed synchronously.

Comment: what makes you say that?

Comment: from the documentation "Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution."

Comment: use this instead of execute asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);